# Laravel POST TokenMismatchException for files bigger than 8kb/16KB (and 2MB) when jwilder/nginx-proxy

Tags: laravel, post, nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I write application in Laravel 5.4 and dockerized it. To use subdomain in my hosting I use `jwilder/nginx-proxy` reverse proxy to redirect requests to my container. In my application allow user to upload files but, when I run it on my hosting and send POST "multipart/form-data" request for files larger than 8kb, then laravel return `TokenMismatchException`. Here is my configuration:

In my `Dockerfile` i use

```
FROM php:7.1.5-alpine
...
ADD ./uploads.php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
...
CMD ... && php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
```

In `uploads.php.ini` I have:

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size =500M
max_execution_time = 600
```

I run jwilder/nginx-proxy in this way:

```
docker pull jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpin
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /path/on/host/to/my_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/my_proxy.conf:ro -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
```

In `my_proxy.conf` (for nginx configuration) I have;

```
server_tokens off;
client_max_body_size 0;
```

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took many hours to test different approach and finnaly i found two solutions. The file `my_proxy.conf` should looks like this:

```
server_tokens off;
client_max_body_size 0;
proxy_request_buffering off;
```

Or like this (for file <=10MB as example)

```
server_tokens off;
client_max_body_size 0;
client_body_buffer_size 10M;
```

The `server_tokens on/off` is not part of problem solution.

Probably problem is because nginx divide 'big' request to smaller one and 'proxy' them separately (so laravel authorize only 'first' segment/part of 'big' request and not authorize other parts).

Of course first proposed solution is better because we not need to set any limit. But if someone want's to set limit into proxy (e.g. 20MB), then should change `client_max_body_size 20M;`.